# How can I change the class of a mathsymbol? (Specifically, from mathrel to mathbin)

Tags: math-mode, spacing, unicode-math

When I use the colon in a math environment  I find that the spacing I need is that of a binary operator (not the spacing of a `mathrel`), e.g., the line $ax+by+ct=0$ in projective space has homogeneous coordinates $(a`\mathbin{:}`b`\mathbin{:}`c)$ and not $(a : b : c)$ (similarly, $10`\mathbin{:}`2=5$ and not $10`\mathrel{:}`2=5$.)
So far I've managed with the following code in the preamble of my document:
`` \mathcode`:="203A `` 
which, I think, changes the class of `:` from `mathrel` to `mathbin` but I'm not sure if it is the right way to achieve that. I found the slot where the symbol `:` sits, basically by trials and errors so I'm not even sure what should I do in a similar situation if I need to change the class of a different symbol.
I understood (maybe I'm wrong) that the first number in `"203A` defines the class of the mathsymbol, e.g., `2` defines a `mathbin` and `3` defines a `mathrel` (which is the default class of the colon).

I would like something which is semantically more evident, like:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathbin{:}}
```

Here is my minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\mathcode`:="203A
\begin{document}
    I could write the homogeneous coordinates of a point  as $(a:b:c:d)$ or $(a\mathord{:}b\mathord{:}c\mathord{:}d)$ or, even worse, $a\mathpunct{:}b\mathpunct{:}c\mathpunct{:}d$, but I'd rather go for $(a\mathbin{:}b\mathbin{:}c\mathbin{:}d)$.
    \begin{align*}
        \texttt{mathrel}\quad & (a\mathrel{:}b\mathrel{:}c)\\
        \texttt{mathord}\quad & (a{:}b{:}c)\\
        \texttt{mathbin}\quad & (a\mathbin{:}b\mathbin{:}c)\\
        \texttt{mathrel}\quad & (a:b:c)
    \end{align*}
Until now I've achieved this with the command \verb*|\mathcode`:="203A| so when I type \verb*|$(a:b:c:d)$| I get $(a\mathbin{:}b\mathbin{:}c\mathbin{:}d)$, that's all.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `` \showthe\mathcode`: ``, but this outputs decimal `12346`. How to get *inside* LaTeX the transformation?

Well, you need to know that the class of relation symbol is 3 and the class of an operation symbol is 2.

If you *do* know that the colon is a relation symbol, you just want to subtract `"1000` (hexadecimal):

```
\mathcode`:=\inteval{\mathcode`:-"1000}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$(a:b:c)$

\mathcode`:=\inteval{\mathcode`:-"1000}

$(a:b:c)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you'd do the redefinition in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \mathcode`:=\inteval{\mathcode`:-"1000}%
}

\begin{document}

$(a:b:c)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, my suggestion is *not* to do this, because the space around the colons would participate to the stretching/shrinking in the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pc}{m}% projective coordinates
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_tmpa_seq \c_colon_str { #1 }
  ( \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \mspace{1\medmuskip}{:}\mspace{1\medmuskip} } )
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\pc{a:b:c}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @egreg, I understood the first part of your answer, and that I should use the second approach (`\ExplSyntaxOn` ...etc) because doing that, the spacing around the colons doesn't get affected. Since I'd like to understand I little bit about the second part of your answer I was wondering if you could give me some advice for a tutorial (in layman's terms).
For example, I don't even understand why your code gives an error on the command `$\pc{a:b:c}$` without calling `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: And a last question: is `\DeclareMathSymbol{:}{\mathbin}{operators}{"3A}`  similar to `\mathcode`:="203A` ?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @Antonio Yes, because the `operators` symbol font is family 0. The error you get without `amsmath` is because you lack `\mspace`. But any document with “serious” math should load `amsmath`.